# Regex: Capturing flanked characters

Tags: python, regex, string, search

I'm trying to match all `GY` or `YG` combinations in my string `QGYGQGYQQG` using the `re` package in python. I place all these matches in a dict for future look-up.

The problem I run into is when `Y` is flanked either side by `G`: Basically my regex can't capture both `GY` *and* `YG` in `GYG` properly.

This is my code so far:

```
import re
seq = 'QYGQGYGQQG'
regex = re.compile('(GY|YG)|(?<=Y)G')
iterator = regex.finditer(seq)
dd = {}
for matchedobj in iterator: 
    dd[matchedobj.group()] = dd.get(matchedobj.group(), []) + [matchedobj.start()]
```

Output:

```
{'G': [6], 'GY': [4], 'YG': [1]}
```

Comment: The newer `regex` module supports overlapping matches.

Comment: Just use `(?=(YG|GY))` with findall

Comment: See [this](https://tio.run/##Dc2xCgIxDIDhvU@RrQlIQZwPx84di9wg2tOAaWsuDoLvXjv8y7f8/WvPVk9jsPSmBlrcXt6wgE85pjhL0TudoCXcmnR@FfR4XjDHX8xEnlxXroYXlLDbVQ3pABIe2j4dj0SwNQUBrqBh43pnK4rzQSuN8Qc) for the `finditer` alternative that also gets you the indices

Comment: Thanks all for the tips! I had no clue that "overlapping matches" was a thing..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the newer `regex` module (or use lookarounds):

```
import regex as re
seq = 'QYGQGYGQQG'

matches = re.findall(r'GY|YG', seq, overlapped=True)
print(matches)
# ['YG', 'GY', 'YG']
```

Or - with `re.finditer`:

```
for m in re.finditer(r'GY|YG', seq, overlapped=True):
    print(m.span())
```

Which would yield

```
(1, 3)
(4, 6)
(5, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution you may use which does not depend on overlapping matches:

```
seq = 'QYGQGYGQQG'
matches = re.findall('G(?=Y)|Y(?=G)', seq)
print([re.sub(r'^Y', 'YG', x.replace('G', 'GY')) for x in matches])
```

This prints:

```
['YG', 'GY', 'YG']
```

The trick here is to match only `G` and `Y`, using a lookahead to assert that what follows is the expected `Y` or `G` needed to make a full match.  This avoids the problem of consuming a second letter which might also be the first letter of another subsequent match.  Then, we take those single letter matches, which represent the full matches, and use a list comprehension to build the original overlapping matches.